# click on option tag gets triggered even when disabled in Angular

Tags: angular, html-select, optgroup

I have a two layered `select` as follows:

```
     <select size="10" class="custom-select mr-4">
        <optgroup label="Properties">
          <option *ngFor="let eachVal of dataProps"
          (click)="getPropValues(eachVal)">
            {{eachVal.property}}
          </option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="References" [disabled]="propClicked">
          <option *ngFor="let eachVal of objProps"
          (click)="getReferenceValues(eachVal)"> <!--Interesting !!!-->
          {{eachVal.property}}</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
```

I want to disable clicking on the References `<optgroup>` when the any `option` from Properties is clicked.

the function `getPropValues()` triggers the `propClicked` boolean flag and I can see the group being disabled, however upon clicking any of the disabled options in References still triggers `getReferenceValues()` function.

is there some precedence of `(click)` over `[disabled]` here?

I have a [working example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-workflow-test).

Comment: this is valid behavior, just because something is disabled, there is no reason why an angular click event should not be processed, a programmer should be able to listen to a click even if the clicked object is disabled

Comment: However, can this behavior change?

Comment: Can you please tell that how you are checking that getReferenceValues is called after being disabled ...I checked your example. First selected one Property,then Reference got disabled and then clicked one reference ...but the value of  'this.referenceClicked' is still false..If getReferenceValues  was called the value of 'this.referenceClicked' should be true.... May be you are indicating some other point..so want to clarify

Comment: one way to do this would be `(click)="!propClicked ? getReferenceValues(eachVal) : null"`

Comment: @Rak2018 If i understand correctly, if something is disabled the click call shouldn't be executed. Atleast that is what a user of the UI might understand. Yet, if I click on the disable reference the `getReferenceValues` is still executed. perhaps it might be wrong understanding on my part

Comment: @Shan   Yes.. I checked that on disable the getReferenceValues  is not getting executed in your program  which is natural...but I want to know how you are checking that it is getting executed .? Have you put any debug/ printing anything in console ? If yes pls can you pls put the screenshot...May be it will help me to get the problem